# Storing a video in a database then retrieving it

Tags: php

Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong with this code, I am connecting to localhost to the database called video. Then I am inserting in to table location and its column location the value `$videoLocation`.

The result I get is when I open my browser is

```
  <?php
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
  ?>
```

What I am trying to achieve with this code is for the video to appear on my webpage once a user has submitted it.

```
    <?php        
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
    $allowType =   array("video/mp4","audio/mp3","audio/wma","image/png","image/gif","image/jpeg");
    $maxSize = 20000000000000;
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $pathToUpload = 'upload/';

      if( in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowType) && in_array($extension,   $allowedExts) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] <= $maxSize)
         {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
         {
      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
          else
           {
           echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

     if (file_exists($pathToUpload . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
     {
         echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
     }
     else
     {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $pathToUpload . $_FILES["file"] ["name"]);
          $videoLocation = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        // now insert $videoLocation into a database table
        $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'video');
        INSERT INTO location (location)
        VALUES ($videoLocation)
       //so you can fetch it on whatever page you feel like
             }
       }
       }
           else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
           }

     ?>
```

Comment: what is this? INSERT INTO location (location)
        VALUES ($videoLocation)

Comment: location is the name of the table, the location inside the brackets is the name of, one of columns in the table.

Comment: _“The result I get is when I open my browser is”_ – is _what_? You get to see the PHP code you posted right after this statement, unparsed – or what?

Comment: I don't think strong video (as binary) in a DB is a good practice. Store it on your filesystem, and store the path in a database. If it gets really large you can easily swap your local disk for something like Amazon S3 (storage).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'video');
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO location (location) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $videoLocation);
$stmt->execute();
//so you can fetch it on whatever page you feel like
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently answer a question for someone else who wanted to store image files in the database. Here is how to do it:

1) the database column must be defined as longblob.

Next, the code uses PDO rather than mysqli.

```
// database connection...
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testmysql';
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then you need an open file handle as follows:

```
$fileVideo  = fopen($videoLocation,'rb');
```

Then you prepare your statement and bind the file:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO location (location) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $fileVideo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$connection->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$connection->commit();
fclose($fileVideo);
```

I haven't test the above on your files but the original code that was like the above but with names changes worked fine.